# tags-input show a a element of an array

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

hi i have a JSON like this:

```
pages[
{
    "id": "74682309",
    "labels": [
      {
        "term": "test1",
        "probability": 0.069
      },
      {
        "term": "test2",
        "probability": 0.037
      }
    ]
}];
```

and using tags-input i want the tags to read only the term and show the term so i can show and update.

i have

```
<tags-input ng-model="se.labels"></tags-input>
```

the '**se**' comes from  **ng-repeat="se in searchCtrl.pages**

Comment: `se.labels.term` won't do the trick?

Comment: no because se.labels have multiple terms and i think when i put term just he doenst know wich one, its not iterating over labels on each term i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation (http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api) you can change the keyProperty and displayProperty to make it use "term" instead of "text"

Comment: done just had to change the displayProperty and it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate how you can obtain the data needed, considering that the provided JSON is a **valid** JSON. Your JSON is invalid.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngTagsInput']);
myApp.factory('data', function() {
    var data = [
{
    "id": "74682309",
    "labels": [
      {
        "text": "test1",
        "probability": 0.069
      },
      {
        "text": "test2",
        "probability": 0.037
      }
    ]
}];

    return data;
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'data', function($scope, data) {    
    var values = [];
    data.map(function(elem) {
        return elem.labels.forEach(function(el) {
            values.push({
                "text" : el.text
            });
        });
    });    

    $scope.tags = values;
}]);
```

And the html part:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="elem">       
        <tags-input ng-model="tags"></tags-input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16554/

**Update:**

You haven't included the angular `ng-tags-input` extension as a tag into your question. Please see my updated fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16557/**

Comment: that part i have my problem is how can the tags-input read it and work with it if i have an array like this  var example= [ "teste", "teste2"] the tags-input works fine but when i try to use the other one it doesnt

Comment: I don't really understand your issue. I've provided a working solution based on your data.

Comment: if u use  <tags-input ng-model="tags"> 
and tags are on your controller $scope.tags=[{ text: "teste"}]
 u will have a input bar with the respective tags
i want the same efect but the respective tags should be the term of my document

but the tags-input dont recognize the "term" i guess because if i change my JSON and replace the word term with text it works fine

Comment: right that way it works but im forced to change the json i dindt wanted that that is my strugle

Comment: As i warned your json is not a valid json!! You have to change the json format. If it's working please accept the answer.